# Make the following statement ACID compliant

Tags: sql, oracle, acid

I can't figure this out. How to make this update statement ACID compliant?

```
Update Students Set Career = 'GRD' where Joined > '2012'
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense - ACIDity is a property of the underlying DBMS generally speaking. It doesn't really make sense to ask how a SQL statement can be ACID - can you clarify what you are trying to do/understand?

Comment: The ACID properties (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) are a property of the RDBMS rather than of an SQL statement.  If the transaction completes — either implicitly because of autocommit or explicitly because of a COMMIT statement, the DBMS is responsible for ensuring the ACID properties.  And for ensuring that if there's a rollback, the DBMS is in the same state as if nothing ever happened.  And it has to ensure this in the presence of concurrent transactions, so that other transactions are unaware of what happened in this one.  Consequently, your question seems a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

If below command is executed it will only update records where it is actually required to change the value of career to 'GRD', if the value is already 'GRD' it won't do anything. Also in case below command is executed multiple times, it won't update the same record again and again:

```
Update Students Set Career = 'GRD' where Joined > 2012 and Career <> 'GRD'
```

Comment: Although that is a good recommendation, it has nothing to do with "making it ACID compliant"

Answer (score -2):

It is joined columns.
Try this query

```
Update Students Set Career = 'GRD' 
where Cast(joined as date) > cast(01-Jan-2015 as date)

2012
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [About] page soon.  I'm not clear how this answer addresses the question — which appears to be asking about the ACID properties of the statement or perhaps DBMS.